# FPDF - AddFont() from TCPDF fonts like (freeserif, kozminproregular,..)

Tags: fpdf

In `TCPDF`, you can use special characters with `freeserif` and `kozminproregular`. But, I wanted to try it to `FPDF`, I tried downloading the `FreeSerif.ttf` and do `cd C:/xampp/etc..` and get the `FreeSerif.php` and `FreeSerif.z` and do the `$pdf->AddFont('freeserif','','FreeSerif.php)`.

BUT the special characters didn`t work, are they not the same? Thanks